# 2009 Honda Accord Radio Replacement

Tags: honda, audio, accord, code

I recently replaced the radio in my 2009 Honda Accord coupe. I did so because the auxiliary function in my old radio stopped working. So, I bought a factory radio with the same face code - 3PA5 - and installed it in my dash. The AC functions work, the clock functions work, but *the audio functions do not work.* The power knob, all of the mode buttons, nothing. Menu button works, but only displays clock settings, no audio settings.

It is not even prompting me to enter the radio code. What do I do now?

Comment: Is it possible that this is because I haven't reassembled the dash entirely? I have the radio clipped in, but no screws have been put back in yet. Same with the storage boxes below and the middle dash panel.

Comment: Did you buy the radio new or used, and were you able to verify it working before is was installed?

Comment: Also, to install the audio (radio and/or navigation) unit in a Honda, I'm pretty sure there should be two sets of codes you need to enter, four for "H" and four for "L" (IIRC). I'm pretty sure they are numbers ranging from 1 through 6. If you don't have the codes, I'd wonder if this isn't the issue.

Comment: Gabe, I bought the radio off of Discount OEM radios, used. Customer service tells me they test them in advance, but I cannot confirm it was working beforehand. 
Paul, I've neither heard of using two codes nor H and L before. I do have a two codes I can try, but given that the radio is unresponsive (outside of clock functions) how would I put them in?